# Looking at quantum physics from the perspective of Indian philosophy?

Tags: quantum-physics

So the philosopher Anand Vaidya, makes the [claim](https://youtu.be/RNmusKn6t_U) (minute 9:18): " .. There was a big movement in Indian philosophy to really look at quantum physics from the perspective of classical Indian philosophy..."

What was the outcome(s) and reception of this movement?

Comment: The physics community ignored it because of its irrelevance. I do not know what the response of the philosophy community was.

Comment: If someone could suggest other tags I could use. Feel free to suggest

Answer (score 1):

There is an author that is not properly someone in this line of Indian Philosophy, but since he came from the perenialist school, he adopts a lot of the language and concepts that exists in Vedanta to translate as we can do similarlly with aristotelian concepts of matter.

His name is Wolfgang Smith: https://www.amazon.com.br/Quantum-Enigma-Finding-Hidden-Key/dp/1597310077

In this book he will talk more about Heisenberg interpretations and his ideas with the aristotelian way to interpret things.

In this another book he talks about the indian philosophy:

https://www.amazon.com.br/Vedanta-Light-Christian-Wisdom-Wolfgang/dp/B0B36B27PP/ref=d_pd_sim_sccl_3_9/131-7276565-5657213?pd_rd_w=f31sy&content-id=amzn1.sym.680628d0-f304-48a4-9bdc-a951a5170d0f&pf_rd_p=680628d0-f304-48a4-9bdc-a951a5170d0f&pf_rd_r=M2G3KSZMY36CVG1SCYXB&pd_rd_wg=l1KVZ&pd_rd_r=846e2299-1e92-4a17-a1bf-e54639932a7c&pd_rd_i=B0B36B27PP&psc=1

Answer (score -1):

In my search on Wikipedia (I'm poor) this came up: [Ājīvika](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80j%C4%ABvika), *Śramaņya* school of thought, allegedly opposed to Vedic Hinduism, that endorsed *hard determinism* and its endpoint in some cases, *fatalism*. Quantum physics, some say, is about *uncertainty* and how the *determinism* of classical physics is *inapplicable* to the world of the really small.

Too, there is no Hindu parallel to the *many worlds* (interpretation) of quantum physics, at least none that I'm aware of.

There's no evidence that Hindu mathematicians developed even a rudimentary theory of (mathematical) probability and without some form of formal system to study *chance*, quantum physics would've been the high hanging fruit, unreachable so to speak.

However ....

Reports, if credible, say that some quantum physics big wigs, like Werner Heisenberg, were drawn towards Hindu philosophy/religion (?); that is to say they saw a connection there that, per critics, has not passed closer scrutiny.

The Hindus also had an *atomic theory*, just like the Greek, Democritus's. So they had, minimally, an inkling of the quantum world. It's sketchy and low on details while high on speculation.

That be all from me ... signing off!

Answer (score -1):

The movement to explore the connections between quantum physics and classical Indian philosophy emerged due to the perceived similarities between certain concepts in both fields. Some proponents of this movement claimed that ideas found in ancient Indian philosophical texts, such as Vedanta, Buddhism, and Jainism, could provide insights into the nature of reality and the underlying principles of quantum physics. Some commonalities cited include the notions of interconnectedness, non-dualism, and the idea that reality is not as straightforward as it appears.

However, the reception of this movement has been mixed. While there are certainly parallels and intriguing philosophical discussions that can arise from comparing these two distinct fields, there are also several challenges and criticisms:

Misinterpretation of Physics: One of the main criticisms is that many proponents of this movement might not have a deep understanding of quantum physics, leading to misinterpretations and superficial connections between the two fields. Quantum physics is a complex and mathematically rigorous discipline, and oversimplifications can lead to erroneous conclusions.

Cherry-Picking of Concepts: Critics argue that proponents of this movement sometimes selectively pick concepts from quantum physics that seem to align with certain aspects of Indian philosophy, while ignoring the broader context of quantum mechanics. This approach can lead to a skewed understanding of both quantum physics and Indian philosophy.

Cultural Appropriation: Some individuals within the scientific community and the Indian philosophical tradition are concerned about the potential for cultural appropriation and misrepresentation of both fields. They caution against overgeneralizing or distorting these intricate subjects for the sake of making connections.

Lack of Scientific Evidence: While there may be interesting philosophical parallels, the movement often lacks empirical evidence to establish a concrete and substantial connection between quantum physics and classical Indian philosophy. The scientific community tends to prioritize evidence-based theories and concepts.

Philosophical vs. Scientific Frameworks: Quantum physics and classical Indian philosophy operate within different frameworks. Quantum physics is a scientific theory grounded in mathematical models and empirical observations, while Indian philosophy is a diverse set of philosophical traditions with varying interpretations and perspectives.

In summary, while the movement to explore the intersection of quantum physics and classical Indian philosophy has generated intriguing discussions and reflections, it has also faced substantial criticism for potential misinterpretations, cherry-picking of concepts, and lack of empirical grounding. The complex nature of both quantum physics and classical Indian philosophy demands a careful and nuanced approach that respects the distinct methodologies and contexts of each field.